# Google Charts, calendar implementation with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to implement this nice calendar chart on my website.

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar

Assume the client performs an ajax request, on page load, and the server queries data from the database and responds with a multidimensional array in JSON Format.

How can i loop through to update the map?

```
 <script>
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["calendar"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
       var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
       dataTable.addRows([
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 15), 38024 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 16), 38108 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 17), 38229 ],
          // Many rows omitted for brevity.
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 4), 38177 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 5), 38705 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 12), 38210 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 13), 38029 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 19), 38823 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 23), 38345 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 24), 38436 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 30), 38447 ]
        ]);

       var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

       var options = {
         title: "Red Sox Attendance",
         height: 950,
       };

       chart.draw(dataTable, options);
   }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate .... so, instead of adding hardcoded data, as in example above, you would like to make ajax request, and fill in that data to chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get a real date from the database via json,
you will need to use google's data table json format,
found here --> [Format of the DataTable Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

and... --> [Dates and Times Using the Date String Representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation)

which means your json will need to be formatted as follows...

```
{
  "cols": [
    {"label": "Date", "type": "date"},
    {"label": "Won/Loss", "type": "number"}
  ],
  "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 13)"}, {"v": 37032}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 14)"}, {"v": 38024}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 15)"}, {"v": 38024}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 16)"}, {"v": 38108}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 17)"}, {"v": 38229}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 4)"}, {"v": 38177}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 5)"}, {"v": 38705}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 12)"}, {"v": 38210}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 13)"}, {"v": 38029}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 19)"}, {"v": 38823}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 23)"}, {"v": 38345}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 24)"}, {"v": 38436}]},
    {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 30)"}, {"v": 38447}]}
  ]}
```

otherwise, you will need to pass some sort of string that can be converted to a date on the client...

incorporating ajax would look something like the following snippet...

note: since the file is not available from here, SO,
the fail callback will be called in the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['calendar']
}).then(function () {
  var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

  var options = {
    title: 'Red Sox Attendance',
    height: 950
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: 'output.txt',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (data) {

    // create data table, draw chart
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);

    $(window).on('resize', function () {
      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    });

  }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {

    // remove in production
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {"label": "Date", "type": "date"},
        {"label": "Won/Loss", "type": "number"}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 13)"}, {"v": 37032}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 14)"}, {"v": 38024}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 15)"}, {"v": 38024}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 16)"}, {"v": 38108}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2012, 3, 17)"}, {"v": 38229}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 4)"}, {"v": 38177}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 5)"}, {"v": 38705}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 12)"}, {"v": 38210}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 13)"}, {"v": 38029}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 19)"}, {"v": 38823}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 23)"}, {"v": 38345}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 24)"}, {"v": 38436}]},
        {"c":[{"v": "Date(2013, 9, 30)"}, {"v": 38447}]}
      ]
    });

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);

    $(window).on('resize', function () {
      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="calendar_basic"></div>
```